# Improve performance of list searching function in r

Tags: r, performance

Morning StackOverflow,

I am creating a function that searches through a single column `ColumnOfDatasetToSearch` of a matrix `Dataset` for a number of search terms `SearchFeatures`. It works well for matrices that have 10^4 rows but really slows down when the row number gets above 10^6 or when `SearchFeatures` has more than a 100 terms. I thought that vectorizing the `ColumnOfDatasetToSearch` would improve my speed but only had modest performance improvement.

```
ListSearcher <- function(SearchFeatures, Dataset, ColumnOfDatasetToSearch){
  RowNumber <- NA
  ColumnOfInterest <- pull(Dataset, ColumnOfDatasetToSearch)
  LengthOfSearchTerms <- length(SearchFeatures)
  for (j in 1:LengthOfSearchTerms){
    if(length(i <- grep(SearchFeatures[j], ColumnOfInterest)))
      RowNumber <- append(RowNumber, i)
  }
  IdentifiersWithThoseSerchTerms <- unique(na.omit((Dataset$Identifiers[RowNumber])))
  return(IdentifiersWithThoseSerchTerms)
}
```

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

NewToCoding

Comment: Hi, I posted an answer. If it does not work, please edit your post, add a small dataset and show how your function is supposed to work with that dataset, that would help.  It can be a small example, just to demonstrate the use. Thanks!

Comment: Fantastic! Your suggestion sped up the code significantly. With 7 search teams and 15 million rows, it went from 2 minutes to 43 seconds and for 368 search terms it went from an hour to 10 minutes. Really appreciate your help! Thanks for sharing your wisdom!

Comment: Good! I made an edit in the post below, which might speed it up even a bit more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine you are using the dataset `iris` and want to return the column `Petal.Length` instead of `Identifiers`.

Does this work? It should be considerably faster

```r
ListSearcher <- function(SearchFeatures, Dataset, ColumnOfDatasetToSearch){
  searchstring <- paste0(SearchFeatures, collapse =  "|")
  selection <- grepl(searchstring, Dataset[[ColumnOfDatasetToSearch]])
  Dataset[selection, ]$Petal.Length
}
# try with a subset of iris
iris[c(1,2,51,52), ]
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
#> 1           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa
#> 2           4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa
#> 51          7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
#> 52          6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor
ListSearcher(c("ver", "se") , iris[c(1,2,51,52), ], "Species")
#> [1] 1.4 1.4 4.7 4.5
```

Edit: since only one column has to be returned, this seems to be a bit faster. Note the last line of the function:

```r
ListSearcher2 <- function(SearchFeatures, Dataset, ColumnToSearch){
  searchstring <- paste0(SearchFeatures, collapse =  "|")
  selection <- grepl(searchstring, Dataset[[ColumnToSearch]])
  Dataset$Petal.Length[selection]
}
```

Microbenchmark comparison:

```r
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  search1 = ListSearcher(c("ver", "se") , iris[c(1,2,51,52), ], "Species"),
  search2 = ListSearcher2(c("ver", "se") , iris[c(1,2,51,52), ], "Species"),
  times = 100000
)
#> Unit: microseconds
#>     expr   min    lq     mean median    uq     max neval
#>  search1 154.5 161.5 201.3834  169.5 189.8 43474.8 1e+05
#>  search2  96.8 101.9 127.6075  106.8 118.7 41666.2 1e+05
```